# Are there Performance Impacts for One Large Table vs Several Smaller Tables in Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise

I'm looking for any input/feedback on real world experiences/troubles with creating one very large table in DSE Cassandra versus a using several more tables and breaking the dataset up somewhat.  Are there impacts to DSE table maintenance, SAI indexing, etc. with larger tables?  The large table will have tens of billions of rows, and use multiple SAI indexes on it as well.  The cluster size itself will have multiple tens of nodes.

Any input/feedback you can provide is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Different tables will allow compaction to run separately, potentially increasing parallelism of compaction (especially LeveledCompactionStrategy, which has limits on moving files between compaction levels in each table).

You'll also probably encounter slightly less btree contention when you write into the memtable if you do different tables. Unclear if you'd actually be able to measure it.

Answer (score 0):

There are certainly some advantages with smaller tables compared to large ones. For example, indexing will be faster by the simple virtue that there's less data to index. Operations like repairing a smaller table is also going to be faster than larger tables (of course, all other things considered equal).

However, such comparison is mostly academic and irrelevant since it has no practical application. In the real world, one does not "choose" to split data into several tables -- it is determined by the access patterns of your application.

If you recall, data modeling in Cassandra requires that you design a table for each application query. Another way of putting it is that the table (1) must contain all the data required for the query, and (2) must be partitioned based on the query filter/predicate. Breaking up the table into smaller "sub-tables" will not work since there are no joins in Cassandra. Cheers!

---

Please support the Apache Cassandra community by hovering over the [cassandra](/questions/tagged/cassandra) tag then click on the `Watch tag` button.  Thanks!

Comment: Out of curiosity, how does watching the [tag:cassandra] tag support the Apache Cassandra community?